# How to Load Webpages From Local Network While LTE Data is Connected?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, internet, 4g, web-server

My device is connected to a local WIFI AP that has a network, but not an internet connection. On this local WIFI network there is a webserver running at `http://192.168.4.1:8000/`

In the browser on my device when I attempt to load the URL the page will fail to load if the devices LTE data is enabled. I assume it's forcing traffic through LTE and thus not finding the page to load since it's looking on the internet instead of the local WIFI network.

If I disable the LTE connection and then load the page in a browser it will load successfully. So I know that the phone can see the web server. It just chooses not to when LTE is enabled.

Is there any way I can force the device to find the page on the local WIFI network even while LTE is enabled, and the device is connected to the internet via LTE, while also being connected to the local WIFI network with the webserver running on it.

Comment: There is an optional feature since Android 12 which could allow that: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency